# Как передать текст с переносами строк в url js?

Tags: javascript, html, url, fetch

Я получаю текст из `textarea`:

`var t = $("#textarea").val()`

Как передать этот текст со всеми переносами строк в url?

Пример:
Текст в textarea:

Hello

word

Нужно передать это в url

```
var t = $("#textarea").val()
fetch(`/test/url&t=${t}`).then((response) => {...})
```

Answer (score 0):

Более корректный вариант в таком случае будет передавать данные через POST, с формированием тела запроса

Comment: Но если не вариант, можно попробовать [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).